# Error de tipeo en el reporte "No es una respuesta"

Tags: bug

Recién fui a reportar una respuesta como "no es una respuesta", y en la descripción hay un typo.

[image: "o se seba eliminar directamente"]

Dice:

> Posiblemente sea una edición, un comentario, otra pregunta, o se **seba** eliminar directamente

Debería decir *deba* en lugar de *seba*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te agradezco el haber encontrado este error.  Lo he modificado y el texto renovado se vera actualizado muy pronto. ¡Gracias!